# Word to describe the occurrence of two adjacent anagrams

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

If you have two words that are anagrams of each other and are used next to each other, what is that occurrence called? *(fee free to correct the way I've phrased the question if it is grammatically incorrect)*

For example, `mane's name`. I realize that this is some form of anthropomorphism, but here the two words are anagrams of each other.

I ask, because `luminous light-bulb` is an example of alliteration. What would this occurrence be called?

Answer (score 6):

> Warden Andrew warned of war end.

I will go so far as to say **There isn't one.** Not every occurrence has a name in English; sometimes you just have to describe it.

(There is obviously alliteration here with the repetition of the initial *w*, but simply using repeated or even consecutive anagrams doesn't have a formal name.)

Comment: "Wander, warned warden Andrew!"

Answer (score 1):

One term that best describes the given example of "mane's name" is ***Semordnilap***:

> *A word or name that spells a different word backwards (notice what  semordnilap spells backwards). Semordnilaps (coined by Martin Gardner in 1961) are also known as backronyms, volvograms, heteropalindromes, semi-palindromes, half-palindromes, reversgrams, mynoretehs, recurrent palindromes, reversible anagrams, word reversals, or anadromes.*

*Answer found via google at http://theweek.com/articles/464433/palindromes-anagrams-9-other-names-alphabetical-antics*

Comment: Note that *name* is not *mane* spelled backwards. Semordnilap may not be appropriate.

Comment: Also I doubt that anyone other than Martin Gardner would ever use this word.